# React Native & Firebase RTDB - having trouble with returns

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using React Native with the Firebase SDK (version 9).  I have a function that is supposed to check in the database to see if I have an access token stored and when it expires if so.  I need the code to return true or false as a result.  I think I'm getting tripped up because 'get' is asynchronous.  Here's what I have currently:

```
export const checkToken = (useruid) => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    let outcome = "not set"
    const userRef = ref(db,'/users/'+useruid);
    get(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('snapshot is', snapshot)
      let expire_time = snapshot.val().expire_time
      if (expire_time > Date.now() + 180000) {
        console.log('expire time is more than 3 min in the future')
        outcome = true 
        return true
      } else {
        console.log('token is stale, snapshot is ',snapshot)
        outcome = false 
        return false
      } 
    
    }   )
    console.log('outcome is now', outcome)
}
```

The last console.log appears first (outcome is now not set), and if I call checkToken in another function (as `console.log(checkToken(someUserID))`, I get back that it is returning undefined.  And then I get all the console logging with the successful snapshot retrieval.

I've read about promises, and async/await, but I'm having trouble translating that to the Firebase RTBD SDK functions.

Many thanks in advance for help/pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just change it to:

```
export const checkToken = async function (useruid) {
    const db = getDatabase();
    let outcome = "not set"
    const userRef = ref(db,'/users/'+useruid);
    await get(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
    .... insert rest of code
```

It should work as you expect.

You mention reading about promises and async/await, but you may want to read about the JS event loop, too. Basically JS doesn't wait for asynchronous actions before moving on to the rest of the code. So the way you have it structured now it kicks off the `get(userRef)` and then just moves on while it waits for that promise to return.